# Syntax error in Java threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am following a starting tutorial for Threading in Java.
The code is very basic

```
public interface Runnable {

void run();

}

public class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

    Thread runner;
    public RunnableThread() {
    }
    public RunnableThread(String threadName) {
        runner = new Thread(this, threadName); // (1) Create a new thread.
        System.out.println(runner.getName());
        runner.start(); // (2) Start the thread.
    }
    public void run() {
        //Display info about this particular thread
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

But I get a parsing error in this line
runner = new Thread(this, threadName);

```
   no suitable constructor found for Thread(RunnableThread,java.lang.String)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String,long) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (actual argument RunnableThread cannot be converted to java.lang.Runnable by method invocation conversion)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (actual argument RunnableThread cannot be converted to java.lang.ThreadGroup by method invocation conversion)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable) is not applicable
  (actual argument RunnableThread cannot be converted to java.lang.ThreadGroup by method invocation conversion)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread(java.lang.Runnable) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.lang.Thread.Thread() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I am using the same code here http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

I searched for this error but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just have token same mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your own definition of Runnable interface

Answer (score 7):

You have created your own Runnable interface.  I suggest you delete it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to implement multithreading in Java..

1. Implement the Runnable interface
2. Extend the Thread Class

Both the approaches have their pros and cons... You dont need your own Runnable interface.. it is already provided.. see following links

[Multithreading tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html)

[Runnable vs Thread](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Multithreading-in-Java/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Runnable interface is already in java Library [predefined interface]
So by mistake, you have declared this interface which stores a new invalid definition.

So at the end now all you need to do is just delete the Runnable.class and Runnable.java files from your PC and then try to recompile this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
runner = new Thread(this, threadName);
```

In this case **this** is RunnableThread. You need to extend RunnableThread by Thread or use

```
Thread.currentThread()
```

instead of **this**

Comment: this is an instance of Runnable, which is fine.  The problem is that he has also created his own Runnable interface which is obviously wrong.